# Forcefully close all unclosed resources in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

My code is basically running on Apache Spark, where each container runs on a separate JVM. You specify a certain memory limit for a container. In my program, a container finishes one task fine, but when it tries to execute another one, it crashes saying memory limits exceeded. If I run each of the task in a separate container, they always run fine. So, it looks like there are some unclosed resources left behind after a task is finished, which I can't figure out in the code, and those unclosed resources increase the memory of the container. So, my question is, is there any way in Java to tell the JVM to forcefully close all the resources. Can I also force garbage collection. I would like to do these two steps at the end of each task.

Comment: No, you really need to take care in your program to clean up unnecessary objects. Java only frees memory for objects eligible for GC (but it does this reliably before throwing OutOfMemory errors).

Comment: You could get the JVM to produce a heap memory dump when going OOM to see what is still around. There is a startup flag for that.

Comment: You cannot in general "close all unclosed resources", since these resources might still be in use by your program. As @Thilo mentioned, a heap dump to analyze any actual leaks is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `System.gc();` but I doubt it is going to help - when running low on memory, Java will garbage collect and only fail if this takes too long. But the way you describe it, **you probably don't have resources (= files, sockets, etc.) open, but large objects *reachable***. Ensure that your returned object does not reference unnecessary intermediate data and to not store anything except constants in `static` variables.

Use e.g. `visualvm` or anything else that can produce a **heap dump** to find which objects hog your memory.

I know that Scala doesn't have this feature. But Java 8 has a nice feature for auto-closing external resources, known as try-with-resources:

```
try(AutoCloseable foo = openSomeResource()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

will automatically call `foo.close();` when leaving this block, no matter how (e.g. exception, return). If you follow this pattern, it's hard to leave resources open. But this refers to what is called "resources" in Java and these have to implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, **you probably don't have resources open, but reachable objects**. There supposedly are many tutorials on how to debug Java/Scala memory leaks. But usually the first step is to get a *heap dump* to see what is using how much memory. Certain tools (e.g. hprof, the JVM built-in) will even be able to show *allocation sites* with line numbers.

Comment: I suppose, that the large objects are referenced in static variables, or somewhere from the main method.

Comment: things from the main method should be GCed when the method returns (except for anything reachable from the return value!) thread locals supposedly become unreachable and GCable when the thread finishes. I suspect it's simply then return value keeping a reference to all the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use try-with-resources in jdk7 or more

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
      }
```